# node.js express-unless exclude a path from middleware.auth

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am looking to use express-unless to exclude a /health path from using middleware.auth.  I am having syntax issues, and I am unable to test this locally.  If I use localSite ==true, it will not work with my environment.  The logs for the snytax is below.  Any help or feedback would be appreciated.

I have tried, 
  `app.use(middleware.auth.unless({ path: ['/health']}));`
 and other combinations, and I continue to get syntax issues.

Below is just a snippet of my code, that has what would be relevant to the middleware auth and the health path.
 var middleware = require('./middleware/middleware');
  var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'); // Enables us to read the cookies from the request headers

```
var middleware = require('./middleware/middleware');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

var unless = require('express-unless');

var express = require('express'),
    //set an instance of express
    app = express(),
    //require the body-parser nodejs module
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),

    //require the path nodejs module
    path = require("path");
//const express = require('express');

var rp = require('request-promise');
var request = require('request');

if (localSite == false) {
  //User cookieparser to validate user's cookie with middleware auth
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.use(middleware.auth);
}
else {
  userN = process.env.USERNAME;
  userMail = process.env.userMail;
}

//healthcheck();
app.get('/health', function(req, res) {
console.log("online");
  res.status(200).end();
});
```

Here is the logs from when I deploy this in bamboo which runs the node server.js which is my application.

```
12-Feb-2020 11:04:18    2020-02-12T11:04.17-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]OUT middleware.js: THIS IS AUTH
12-Feb-2020 11:04:18    2020-02-12T11:04.17-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]ERR   app.use(middleware.auth.unless({ path: ['/health']}));
12-Feb-2020 11:04:18    2020-02-12T11:04.17-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]OUT middleware.js: node_env=development
12-Feb-2020 11:04:18    2020-02-12T11:04.17-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]ERR /home/vcap/app/server.js:99
12-Feb-2020 11:04:18    2020-02-12T11:04.18-0500 [CELL/SSHD/0]OUT Exit status 0
12-Feb-2020 11:04:18    2020-02-12T11:04.17-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]ERR                           ^
12-Feb-2020 11:04:18    2020-02-12T11:04.17-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]ERR TypeError: middleware.auth.unless is not a function
12-Feb-2020 11:04:18    2020-02-12T11:04.17-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]ERR     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vcap/app/server.js:99:27)
12-Feb-2020 11:04:18    2020-02-12T11:04.17-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]ERR     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
12-Feb-2020 11:04:18    2020-02-12T11:04.17-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]ERR     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
12-Feb-2020 11:04:18    2020-02-12T11:04.17-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]ERR     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
12-Feb-2020 11:04:18    2020-02-12T11:04.17-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]ERR     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
12-Feb-2020 11:04:18    2020-02-12T11:04.17-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]ERR     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
12-Feb-2020 11:04:18    2020-02-12T11:04.17-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]ERR     at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
12-Feb-2020 11:04:18    2020-02-12T11:04.17-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]ERR     at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
12-Feb-2020 11:04:18    2020-02-12T11:04.17-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]ERR     at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

Here is my middleware.js which I am importing.

```
var reactExpressMiddleware = require('react-express-middleware');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'); // Use package for decoding/verifying JWTs
var jwkToPem = require('jwk-to-pem'); // Use JWK2PEM to convert from JWK sets into PEM keys
//var jwksClient = require('jwks-ec'); // Set up info for JWKS Client to reach out to JWKS server and grab appropriate PublicKeys
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'); // Enables us to read the cookies from the request headers 
// const express = require('express');

var jwksClient = require('../dnaModule/jwks-ec');

var express = require('express'),
    //set an instance of exress
    app = express(),
    //require the body-parser nodejs module
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),

    //require the path nodejs module
    path = require("path");

var node_env = process.env.NODE_ENV;

console.log("middleware.js: NODE ENV::::::::" + node_env);

if (node_env == "test") {
    var jwks_url = 'https://test.com/pa/oidc/JWKS';
    var cookie_name = 'PA.info';
}

const client = jwksClient({

    cache: true,
    cacheMaxEntries: 5, // Default value cacheMaxAge: '5h', // Default value
    rateLimit: true,
    jwksRequestsPerMinute: 10, // Default value
    strictSsl: true, // Default value
    jwksUri: jwks_url // Test Endpoint

});


notAuthorizedMsg = "Not authorized.  You must belong to the auth group."
module.exports = {
    auth: function (req, res, next) {
    let decodedUser = null;
        console.log('middleware.js: CHECK JWT!!!!!!!!!!');
        // Check to see if JWT exists
        if (typeof req.cookies[cookie_name] == "undefined") {
            //send a 403 API access error
            res.status(403).send(notAuthorizedMsg);
        }
        else {
             console.log('middleware.js: NOT UNDEFINED!!!!!!!!!!');
            //next();
            // Get JWT and pull out the KID from request cookies
            var token = req.cookies[cookie_name].toString();

            var decoded = jwt.decode(token, {complete: true});
            //console.log('middleware.js: token == ' + token);
            //console.log('User_name == ' + user_name);
            // Check for bogus token
            if (decoded == null) {
                res.status(403).send(notAuthorizedMsg);
            }
            else {
                //console.log(typeof decoded.header);
                var reloadRequest = false;
                var kid = decoded.header.kid.toString();
                console.log("middleware.js: KID ==" + kid);
                // Retrieve signing public key
                client.getSigningKey(kid, function (err, key) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("middleware.js: Error: ", err);
                        var reloadRequest = true;
                        //Reload the page if the key fetch fails, DNS will resolve.
                        //res.redirect('back');
                    }
                    else {
                     console.log('middleware.js: CONVERT KEY!!!!!!!!!');
                        const signingKey = key;
                        // Convert JWK to PEM for public key format
                        var cert = jwkToPem(signingKey);

                        // Verify the JWT against the public key
                        jwt.verify(token, cert, {algorithms: ['ES256']}, function (err, decodedToken) {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log('middleware.js: Error:', err.message);
                                var reloadRequest = true;
                            }
                            else {
                             console.log('middleware.js: DECODED!!!!!!!!!!');
                                //set req.user with the JWT fields from the decoded/verified token
                                //req.user = decodedToken;
                                //return next();
                                 decodedUser = decodedToken;
                            }
                        });
                    }

                if (reloadRequest) {
                        console.log('middleware.js: Attempting Reload of page');
                        res.redirect('back');
                    } 
                    else if (decodedUser == null || typeof decodedUser === "undefined") {
                        console.log('middleware.js: Not Authorized, no valid decoded token found');
                        res.status(403).send(notAuthorizedMsg);
                    } 
                    else if (typeof decodedUser.groups === "undefined") {
                        console.log('middleware.js: Not Authorized, no groups returned');
                        res.status(403).send(notAuthorizedMsg); 
                    }
                    else {
                        //console.log('middleware.js: Groups are ' + decodedUser.groups);

                        // A single LDAP group is not returned in an Array whereas multiple are
                        // so we need to check before we do an includes check if we need
                        // to iterate over the groups list
                        let hasGroup = false;
                        if (decodedUser.groups instanceof Array) {
                            for (var i = 0; i < decodedUser.groups.length; i++) {
                              if (decodedUser.groups[i].includes('grouptest')) { 
                                hasGroup=true;
                                break;
                              }
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            hasGroup = decodedUser.groups.includes('grouptest');
                        }

                        if (hasGroup) {
                            res.cookie('sc_user', JSON.stringify({firstName}), {overwrite: true});
                            console.log('middleware.js: Name: ' + decodedUser.firstName + ' ' + decodedUser.lastName);
                            //console.log("middleware.js: All data: %o", decodedUser);

                            var nID = decodedUser.sub;

                            module.exports.first_name = decodedUser.firstName;
                            module.exports.last_name = decodedUser.lastName;


                            next();  

                        }
                        else {
                            console.log('middleware.js: not authorized');
                            res.status(403).send(notAuthorizedMsg);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Your code doesn't show anywhere `unless` is used?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Usage notes](https://github.com/jfromaniello/express-unless), You need to add the below snippet like this, (you can add this after your `var request = require('request');` statement)

```
middleware.auth.unless = unless;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't follow what you mean by next to?  I very rarely code in node.  

 `middleware.auth.unless = unless;`
Should be after the
 `var request = require('request');`
 statement?

Comment: i would get this typeError though?  middleware.auth.unless = unless;
           ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'auth' of undefined

Comment: Are you exporting your `middleware.auth` ?, Can you please update your post with your `middleware.auth` code?

Answer (score 0):

Using express v4 at the time of this answer, place routes you don't want the middleware to intercept **before** using the middleware, like so:

```js
app.get('/route1', (req, res) => res.send('Route without middleware'));

app.use(yourMiddleware());

app.get('/route2', (req, res) => res.send('Route with middleware'));
```

**Edit:** 
You can still choose to run middleware **any time** in the endpoints defined before middleware by using the next() native middleware provided by express, like so:

```js
app.get('/route1', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Middleware not executed');
    next(); // This runs yourMiddleware() and executes any code defined further in THIS endpoint
    console.log('Middleware executed');
    res.send('Weird endpoint...');
});

app.use(yourMiddleware());

app.get('/route2', (req, res) => res.send('Route with middleware'));
```